# Module granularity strategies

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm building a KnockoutJS web app using RequireJS to modularize it. I'm trying to decide between a couple of strategies to break things into modules.

**Flat approach**:
One approach features a flatter directory structure and larger modules:

```
/webapp
 |-/scripts
    |-/templates
    |  |-car_edit.html
    |  |-car-view.html
    |  |-person_edit.html
    |  |-person_view.html
    |-main.js
    |-person.js
    |-car.js
```

As an example, the person module (in person.js) is implemented something like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', ...], function($, ko, ...) {

  var PersonViewModel = function PersonViewModel() { ... };

  var load = function load(id) { ... };

  var create = function create() { ... };

  var view = function view(element, model) { ... };

  var edit = function edit(element, model) { ... };

  return {
    Model : PersonViewModel, // exposes ViewModel for testing
    create : create,         // reserve id on server, return new empty Person
    load : load,             // get data from server, return new Person w/ data
    view : view,             // load view template, bind Person
    edit : edit              // load edit template, bind Person
  };
});
```

**Deep structure approach:**
Another approach would use a deeper directory structure with smaller modules:

```
/webapp
 |-/scripts
    |-/car
    |  |-/templates
    |  |  |-edit.html
    |  |  |-view.html
    |  |- Model.js
    |  |- view.js
    |  |- edit.js
    |  |- create.js
    |  |- load.js
    |-/person
    |  |-/templates
    |  |  |-edit.html
    |  |  |-view.html
    |  |- Model.js
    |  |- view.js
    |  |- edit.js
    |  |- create.js
    |  |- load.js
    |-main.js
```

The code is similar to the example before, except each part of the module is now it's own module:

```
//  /person/Model.js
define(['jquery', 'knockout', ...], function($, ko, ...) {

  return function Model() { ... };

});


//  /person/view.js:
define(['jquery', 'knockout', ...], function($, ko, ...) {

  return function view(element, model) { ... };

});
```

Et cetera.

Is either approach preferred? Is there a better approach I'm missing?

Comment: I tend to go with something close to your first approach.  however. i have a viewmodel subfolder as well where main.js,person.js andcar.js would live.  obviously both ways work.  its just a case of keeping all your coders creating files consistently

Answer (score -1):

With Backbone/Require we are using [this Boilerplate](https://github.com/gfranko/Backbone-Require-Boilerplate), I think you can use it with another framework with small adjusment.

It is very complete, and it is very easy to find a module, even if you find the code for the first time.