# How to organize a SPA with KnockoutJS, SammyJS and pagerJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, sammy.js, pagerjs

I've just got started using KnockoutJS and I'm using it in a combination with PagerJS, SammyJS and BootStrap to build a single page app and I'm a bit lost right now.

What's startling me is how am I supposed to organize the viewmodels and combine routing and pages in a simple and reusable way? Right now it feels like a pile of loose bits that doesn't really fit, just almost. I've checked some answers on SO and but I have still not get to grips with how to organize the app.

At the moment I'm having one viewmodel on the page, as a proof of concept, and it just handles the display of personal information and upcoming events for users. However, now I have to incorporate other type of information and it doesn't seem right to have one viewmodel, rather multiple viewmodels as the user is expected to be able  to administer his/her events, contacts and tasks and list other users, events and tasks, among other things. Yet more is to come.

Almost all options that a user is to select/choose are defined in the database. For example user tasks and corresponding actions to solve these tasks are predefined in the database.

Most examples tend to put the SammyJS routing in the viewmodel but when having multiple viewmodels on a page I would like to move SammyJS from the single viewmodel to be on its own, ie have one single place to edit the routes.

My thought has been to use PagerJS to switch between different views easily, but it requires a sync between the paths set in SammyJS and the data-bound paths used for PagerJS. For example when selecting #!/user then the routing in Sammy handles the request and fetches the data to be displayed and PagerJS shows the user page. Feels a bit fragile to me but that is perhaps how it is supposed to work.

Comment: You could also take a look at [Knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/); a framework which takes "best of the both worlds" of Knockout and Backbone (incl. Routing and history support).

Answer (score 2):

Some caveats beforehand:

I'm using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to divide my app up into modules - this isn't necessarily required (no pun intended) - you could just dump everything in one Javascript file and have it work, I just find it easier to organize and work with. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324123/module-granularity-strategies) shows how my project is laid out.

I'm also not using SammyJS for routing, but [Crossroads](http://millermedeiros.github.com/crossroads.js/) and Hasher.  The concepts should be somewhat the same though.

The examples below probably aren't a 100% match for what you're doing, but hopefully it gives you an idea of the approach I'm using.

My `main.js` contains all the routing info, and inside each route handler, I use `require()` from RequireJS to pull in the module(s) I'm using for that route.  Each module contains the Knockout ViewModel and several methods to do things like load data for the ViewModel, bind it in certain contexts, etc.

`main.js` here's how I handle the route to show the `#/person/id` route:

```
crossroads.addRoute("person/{id}", function(id){
    require(["person"], function(person) {
        var model = person.load(id);
        person.view($('#content'), model);
    });
});
```

Significant parts of `person.js`:

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', ...], function($, ko, ...) {
    var person = {};
    person.Model = function Model(id) {
        this.id = ko.observable(id);
        this.name = ko.observable();
        // more properties and methods removed...
    };

    person.load = function(id) {
        var model = new person.Model(id);
        var request = $.ajax({
            // ajax config properties removed...
            'success' : function(resp) {
                model.name (resp.name);
                // more property setting removed...
            }
        });
        return model;
    };

    person.view = function(element, model) {
        // Using require text plugin to load templates...
        require(['text!templates/person/view.tmpl.html'], function(ViewTemplate) {
            element.empty();
            element.html(ViewTemplate).ready(function() {
                ko.applyBindings(model, element.get(0));
                // any further setup needed below...
            });
        });
    };
    return person;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your approach definitely seems interesting. You don't use any helper library like pagerjs to switch between the views -  I assume you are using a template for each view instead? I'm thinking of getting rid of the pagerjs as for now as it it messes up my perception of how I should carry on.